# SQL if case true then look at different column values and count it

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't find an answer for my problem.

I have this data :

```
Name  | Total | YTD  
------+-------+----
Item1 | 1     | 1
Item2 | 2     | 1
```

It should run like: if Total has value 1 then it need to look at YTD column, if column has value then show ratio between them. I NEED Total value too of all 1. is it possible to achieve it?

I tried this way:

```
CASE 
   WHEN TOTAL = 1 
      THEN YTD 
      ELSE RATIO 
END AS RESULT.
```

What it should look: Case when total =1 then check YTD if true count sum and find ratio.

Comment: Try ```if(Total = 1,YTD, YTD / Total)``` for the column you describe.

Comment: i tried IF(Total = 1, YTD, YTD / Total). but the problem is that table can have a lot of different names, and i need count how many are diffrent total names, and how many total names for this particular case have YTD.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in many ways. For example user case stmt

```
   select case  when Total = 1 then
                              YTD
                             else
                              ratio
                           end as result
                      from tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this
select case
        when (total = 1 and ytd<>NULL)  then 
                    ytd/total
                else
                    total 
            end as result
from tablename